# Problem with using git with mongodb in command prompt

Tags: mongodb, git, go

I am having trouble getting `go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo` working:
As I type it into my command prompt nothing shows up after, it just leaves it blank after a few mometns and it returns to my `c:\user`.

Can anyone let me know what i am doing incorrectly

[image: error message]

Using any other go get with other packages works fine.
When I create a directory and use

```
go mod init github.com/example/example
```

it installs fine, but can not be used in my program

Comment: There are no go files in that package. Instead of trying to get the driver, use the go modules system. Write your program with go modules, import the driver, and when you run `go build`, it should get all the required packages.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your `%GOPATH%\bin` folder (if GOPATH is not defined: `%USERPROFILE%\go\bin`)

```
dir /OD %USERPROFILE%\go\bin
```

If you see a binary created recently, the go get shoul have worked (build+install)

If the build was enough( meaning no binary to install), check if a simple program at least compile:

```
import (
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
```